# How can I use ajax to populate a UL with rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a UL that I want to be populated dynamically by an ajax call to rails.

How can I use ajax to dynamically populate a different page (being served by a different controller) with that information, i.e. the group.links collection for one group?

possibly something like

so I look for a click and then want to populate the list so I have this javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-show-group-members]='true'").bind('click', function() {
    var gid= $(this).data("id");
    var gname= $(this).data("name");
    var links=$.get('/groups/' + gid);
    $('<tr><td colspan="4">Members:</br><ul id="group-members"><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>Delete the <b>'+gname+'</b> group and all its members: <b><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href=\'/groups/'+gid+'\'>Yes</a></b> <b><a href="groups" data-close-group="true">No</b></br></br>').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
    $(this).html("");
  });
});
```

the list is a placeholder though that I want to be populated dynamically.

I was thinking of adding:

```
  var gid=$(this).data("id"); # comes from the url data attribute
  $.ajax({
    url: '/groups/$gid',
    type: 'get',
    data: $('#group-members').sortable('serialize'),
    dataType: 'script'
  });
});
```

but not if that is right.

I have an existing route - `groups/:id` that, through the groups show method, populates `@members` which I use in the group show page erb template to show members for that group.
Currently the groups show method is

```
  def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @members = Link.find_all_by_group_id(params[:id], :order => 'position')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @group }
    end
  end
```

so I could use the `format.xml` or I could add `format.json` but how do I call that and end up with a UL that has the group names.

Group is:

```
id: integer, group_name: string, 
created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, group_description: string
```

the page uses:

```
<ul id="group-members"></ul>
```

as a place to receive this information.  I can obviously remove the placeholder `li`'s

Answer (score 0):

May be able to utilize:

```
// Get the json from the controller
function GetListItems() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/JsonService/GetItems",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            DisplayListItems(result);
        },
        "error": function (result) {
            var response = result.responseText;
            alert('Error loading: ' + response);
        }
    });
}

// Create list items and append them inside <ul> element
function DisplayListItems(list) {
    $.each(list, function(index, element) {
        var itemHTML = ["<li>",
                                "<div>",
                                    "<div>",
                                        element.Title,
                                    "</div>",
                                    "<div>",
                                        element.Description,
                                    "</div>",                                    
                                "</div>",
                            "</li>"].join('\n');
        $(".list > ul").append(itemHTML);
    }
}

// Controller method that serves json data
public JsonResult GetItems()
{
    IQueryable<Item> itemList = new DAO().GetList();

    return Json(from e in itemList
                select new
                {
                    Title = e.Title,
                    Description = e.Description
                });
}
```

Not sure of the format to add for my groups controller show.

Just

```
format.json
```

or perhaps

```
format.json {render @members}
```